# Exchange Online "Standard protection" preset vs Exchange Online Protection?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I noticed my 'tenant' had this Standard Protection preset off. Apparently this is supposed to be the 'baseline protection profile".

However, everywhere I am reading that EOP is enabled by default and protecting already by default.

So which one is it?

Do I have t enable this 'standard protection' to get any protection?
What is the difference between leaving the "standard protection" preset on and off?

Answer (score 0):

By default, only built-in protection is enabled and assigned to everyone. For Standard and Strict preset security policies, they won't until they manually assign the policy to users Assign to anyone.

You don't need to enable this standard protection to get any protection. Instead, standard protection is assigned to designated users to improve the security of specific users.

This official document provides detailed differences between the three protections for your reference:
[Preset security policies - Office 365 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/preset-security-policies?view=o365-worldwide#profiles-in-preset-security-policies)

Comment: Just wanted to check if the answer shared below helped. If it helped, then would request you to please "Accept the answer" as it would be helpful to others in the community as well.